# Find a function $F$ on $[0,1]$ with moments decaying as $(\ln n)^{-n}$

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series

Let $F:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that
$$
\mu_n(F)=\int_0^1F(t)t^ndt\sim\frac1{(\ln n)^n}\quad\mbox{as}\quad n\to\infty.
$$
More precisely, 
$$
0<c<|\mu_n(F)|(\ln n)^n<C<\infty,\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
Note that in this case the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mu_n(F)z^n
$$
represents an entire function. The generating function
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\mu_n(F)z^n}{n!}
$$
is an entire function of minimal exponential type. I am not aware of any explicit description of such a function, so this is already a sign.

**Question:** Can we find an explicitly given such function $F$? Here by "explicitly given" I mean in a "closed form", e.g., no series.

I think that by convexity arguments it can be shown that $F$ cannot be non-negative (non-positive). In fact, I do not need $F$ be a function; $F(x)dx$ may be a signed measure on $[0,1]$, just given explicitly.

Thank you.

Comment: Indeed it is clear that these can't be the moments of a positive measure since then $\int t^n \, d\rho(t) \gtrsim c^n$ for some $c>0$ (unless $\rho = \delta_0)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\supp}{\operatorname{\mathrm supp}}
\newcommand{\cch}{\operatorname{\mathrm cch}}
$
If $F\in L^2$, then the condition 
\begin{equation*}
 |\mu_n(F)|(\ln n)^n<C<\infty\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
implies that $F=0$ almost everywhere (a.e.) on $[0,1]$.

Indeed, let 
\begin{equation*}
 f(z):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\mu_n(F)(iz)^n}{n!}
 =\int_0^1 F(t)\,dt \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(itz)^n}{n!}
 =\int_0^1 F(t)e^{itz}\,dt
\end{equation*}
for all complex $z$. 
By (1), for any natural $k\ge2$
\begin{equation*}
 |f(z)|\le O(1+|z|^{k-1})+C\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{(|z|/\ln n)^n}{n!}
\le O(1+|z|^{k-1})+C\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(|z|/\ln k)^n}{n!}
\le c_k e^{|z|/\ln k}
\end{equation*}
for some real $c_k>0$ and all complex $z$. 
So, $f(z)$ is an entire function of exponential type $a$ for any real $a>0$.

Hence, by a [Paley--Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem) (more specifically, see e.g. [Theorem 19.3 on page 375](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwidramz0vHhAhUHQq0KHVAcCicQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2F59clc.files.wordpress.com%2F2011%2F01%2Freal-and-complex-analysis.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3_ZfMwIfUWx3Lrt4d_zS5e)), for each real $a>0$ there is an $L^2$ function $F_a$ such that for all complex $z$ 
\begin{equation*}
 f(z)=\int_{-a}^a F_a(t)e^{itz}\,dt
\end{equation*}
Taking the inverse Fourier transform, we see that for each $a\in(0,1)$ and all complex $z$
\begin{equation*}
 f(z)=\int_0^a F(t)e^{itz}\,dt. 
\end{equation*}
Thus, for all complex $z$
\begin{equation*}
 0=f(z)=\int_0^1 F(t)e^{itz}\,dt. 
\end{equation*}
So, indeed $F=0$ a.e. on $[0,1]$.

---

Consider now the more general setting when $F(t)\,dt$ is replaced by $\rho(dt)$, where $\rho$ is a signed measure over $\R$ with support $\supp\rho\subseteq[0,1]$. Then  condition (1) is replaced by 
\begin{equation*}
 |\mu_n(\si)|(\ln(n+2))^n<C<\infty\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_0:=\{0,1,\dots\}, \tag{1a}
\end{equation*}
where 
\begin{equation*}
 \mu_n(\si):=\int_0^1 t^n\si(dt)=\int_0^1 t^{n+2}\rho(dt)\quad\text{and}\quad\si(dt):=t^2\rho(dt). 
\end{equation*}
So, $\supp\si\subseteq[0,1]$. Also, (1a) implies $\mu_0(\si)<\infty$, that is, the signed measure $\si$ is finite. So, by reasoning quite similar to that in the above $L^2$ case, we see that under condition (1a) 
\begin{equation*}
 f(z):=\int_\R e^{itz}\,\si(dt)
\end{equation*}
is an entire function of exponential type $a$ for any real $a>0$.

For real $b>0$ and $t\in\R$, let 
\begin{equation*}
 G_b(t):=(g_b*d\si)(t):=\int_\R g_b(t-s)\,\si(ds)
 =\frac{\si([t-b,t+b])}{2b}, 
\end{equation*}
where $g_b:=\frac1{2b}\,1_{[-b,b]}$. Then $G_b\in L^2(\R)$, since the signed measure $\si$ is finite with $\supp\si\subseteq[0,1]$. Also, 
\begin{equation*}
 \hat g_b(z):=\int_\R e^{itz}g_b(t)\,dt=\frac{\sin bz}{bz}
\end{equation*}
for $z\ne0$, and hence 
\begin{equation*}
 f_b(z):=\int_\R e^{itz}\,G_b(t)\,dt
 =\int_\R e^{itz}\,(g_b*d\si)(t)\,dt=\hat g_b(z)f(z)
\end{equation*}
is of exponential type $b+a$ for all real $a>0$. Thus, by the cited Paley--Wiener theorem, $\supp(g_b*d\si)\subseteq[-b-a,b+a]$ for all real $a>0$ and hence 
\begin{equation*}
 \supp(g_b*d\si)\subseteq[-b,b]. 
\end{equation*}

On the other hand, because $\supp g_b$ and $\supp\si$ are both compact, by [Theorem 4.3.3 on page 117](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwigxZCtvvXhAhUR16wKHcMWCMkQFjAEegQIBxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lama.univ-savoie.fr%2F~raibaut%2FHormander-LPDOI.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3ozf7r2YsA4HKPwTiAFpZ_), $\cch\supp(g_b*d\si)=\cch\supp g_b+\cch\supp\si$, where $\cch$ denotes the closed convex hull. Since $\cch\supp g_b\ni0$, we conclude that $\cch\supp\si\subseteq\cch\supp(g_b*d\si)\subseteq[-b,b]$, whence 
$\supp\rho\subseteq\supp\si\cup\{0\}\subseteq[-b,b]$, for any real $b>0$. Thus, condition (1a) implies 
\begin{equation*}
\supp\rho\subseteq\{0\}. \tag{2} 
\end{equation*}

Vice versa, trivially (2) implies (1a). Thus, (1a) holds iff $\supp\rho\subseteq\{0\}$.

---

**Response to the second comment by the OP:**
Let us try to sort all this out.

1. Your condition 
   \begin{equation}
   0<c<|\mu_n(F)|(\ln n)^n<C<\infty \quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N} \tag{3} 
   \end{equation} 
   can actually never hold as stated, because the inequalities $0<c<|\mu_n(F)|(\ln n)^n$ will always be false for $n=1$. So, of course, I assumed (3) with $\mathbb{N}$ replaced by $\{2,3,\dots\}$.
2. In your post here, you did not even mention "analytical distributions" or Ehrenpreis. Instead, you wrote: "Let $F:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function" and then you also wrote "In fact, I do not need $F$ be a function; $F(x)dx$ may be a signed measure on $[0,1]$".
3. If $F(x)dx$ is replaced by a signed measure $\rho(dx)$, then the corrected version of your condition (3) can be rewritten as the conjunction of my condition (1a) and the condition 
   \begin{equation}
   0<c<|\mu_n(\si)|(\ln n)^n \quad\forall n\in\{2,3,\dots\}. \tag{4}
   \end{equation}
4. It was shown in this answer that, under condition (1a), the support of the signed measure $\rho$ must be contained in the set $\{0\}$. (Method-wise, this was first done in the case when $\rho(dx)=F(x)dx$ with $F\in L^2$, and then extended to the general case of any signed measure $\rho$ on $[0,1]$.)
5. It then immediately follows that there is no signed measure $\rho$ on $[0,1]$ satisfying (1a) and (4) -- or, equivalently, satisfying the corrected version of your condition (3). In other words, your conditions do result in a contradiction. This completely answers your posted question.

Comment: I have added an extension to the more general setting when $F(t)\,dt$ is replaced by $\rho(dt)$, where $\rho$ is a signed measure.

Comment: Paley-Wiener theorem (e.g., Theorem 19.3 in Ruding you refer to) requires $f(z)$ be $L^2$ on the real line, which is not true, I think (there are reasons why it shouldn't). Same is true for $f_b(z)$ in your second application of Paley-Wiener, I think. But I can see your point. If $f$ is of minimal exponential type and $F$ (or $\rho$) its Fourier transform, then $F$-s support is $\{0\}$. Instead of classical Paley-Wiener you can use other things (f.i., a la Ehrenpreis). Thank you.

Comment: @Bedovlat : Since $F\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, by the Plancherel theorem $f=\hat F$ is also $L^2$ on $\mathbb R$. See e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlancherelsTheorem.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem . So, I see no problem here. (You may have confused my $f(z)$ with your (moment) generating function $f(-iz)$.)

Comment: Dear Prof. Pinelis, your $f(-iz)$ is also an entire function of minimal exponential type, and thus cannot be $L^2$ on the real line. No one cancelled Plancherel theorem, of course, but what I am saying is that your assumption $F\in L^2$ is already in contradiction with your (1). In fact, $F$ cannot be even a distribution in the classical sense. It can be viewed as an "analytical distribution" in the sense of Ehrenpreis, as I wrote before.

Comment: @Bedovlat : In my answer, I have added a detailed response to your latter comment. I hope this will help. Here I wanted to add that whatever may be said about $f(-iz)$ is irrelevant to my answer, dealing with $f(z)$. More importantly, we indeed get a contradiction. But this contradiction results from your own assumptions, not mine. In the answer, I did not make any assumptions in addition to yours.

Comment: Professor Pinelis, what I said above pertains to BOTH $f(z)$ AND $f(-iz)$, and IS relevant to your answer. In fact, it shows that you did not need to expand all those details of undergraduate analysis. At the very moment when you realized that $f$ is the Fourier transform of $F$, the answer was already clear by what I wrote in the above comments. But, well, if you do not know that, then assuming that $F$ is $L^2$ or a measure and arriving at a contradiction is also legitimate. I never said that your post does not answer my question; it does. And I think that I thanked you above.